# erro ao converter uma procedure do Oracle em uma função do PostgreSql na linguagem pl/pgsql

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, postgresql, funções, procedure

Adaptei o código, porém consta o seguinte erro :

> ERRO: relação "campos" não existe CONTEXT: compilação da função PL/pgSQL "p_grava_log"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_GRAVA_LOG (
  TIPO character varying,  
  C_TABELA  character varying,  
  C_CAMPOS_CHAVE  character varying,  
  C_CHAVES  character varying, 
  --VALOR DO CAMPO CHAVE  C_USUARIO NUMERIC,  
  C_MODULO  character varying)  RETURNS TEXT AS    

    $BODY$

  DECLARE 
    V_CAMPOS  character varying(6000);    
    V_SQL  character varying(32000); 
    CAMPOS RECORD;
    CAMPOS1  CAMPOS%ROWTYPE;


  BEGIN 

    FOR CAMPOS IN 
    SELECT column_name 
      FROM information_schema.columns 
     WHERE table_name = C_TABELA
     ORDER BY ordinal_position LOOP      
      V_CAMPOS := V_CAMPOS || CAMPOS.COLUMN_NAME || ','; 
    END LOOP; 
    V_SQL := 'INSERT INTO ' || 
             ' l_'||C_TABELA||' (' || V_CAMPOS || ') ' || 
             '  SELECT ' || V_CAMPOS  || 
             '    FROM ' || C_TABELA || 
             '   WHERE ' || C_CAMPOS_CHAVE || ' = ' || C_CHAVES; 

     EXECUTE  V_SQL; 
       Return V_SQL;     

  END;  $BODY$
```

LANGUAGE plpgsql

Comment: Coloca a `procedure` originalmente em [tag:plsql].

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta na linha:

```
CAMPOS1  CAMPOS%ROWTYPE;
```

Você não pode declarar `CAMPOS1` com o tipo de dado `CAMPOS%ROWTYPE` pois não existe uma tabela (relação) com o nome `CAMPOS`. Apenas declarar `CAMPOS1` como `RECORD` é o suficiente.

Note que você se quer esta utilizando esta variável, portanto ela pode ser removida, a não ser que a esteja utilizando em outro trecho de código que não o postado.